# How should I use Interfaces for connecting the core of my application to the UI?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, interface

I am writing an application in VB.NET, where various calculations are performed in the Core class. They are called by user inputs in the MainWindow class (UI). When calculations are complete, they are displayed in the MainWindow again.

Trying to avoid spaghetti code and accidentally making Core dependent on UI, it is my understanding that I should be using Interfaces. I think I understand how Interfaces work, but I am not sure how to properly implement it for two-way communication between the Core and the UI.

A very simple example follows.

Core class:

```
Public Module Core
    Public UI As UIinterface
        
    Sub Init()
        UI = New MainWindow
    End Sub
        
    Sub RunCalculations()
        Dim calculationResult As String = 5 + 5         
        UI.DisplayResults(calculationResult)
    End Sub

End Module
```

UIInterface interface:

```
Public Interface UIInterface
    Sub DisplayResults(results as String)
End Interface
```

And the my MainWindow class:

```
Class MainWindow
    Implements UIInterface
    
    Private Sub DisplayResults(results as String) Implements UIInterface.DisplayResults
        label1.text = results
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub RunButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Core.RunCalculations() 'This is probably wrong
    End Sub 
End Class
```

As you can I see, I don't get how should I pass the button click to the Core. It is my understanding that this should be done through UIInterface somehow, but I can't figure it out, and I can't seem to find any relevant examples anywhere. All I'm finding on the Interface usage is one-way communication.

Can someone please advise? If my understanding of how Interfaces flawed? If so, what would be the correct implementation that separates Core from UI as much as possible, making it easy later on to switch to another UI implementation without changing anything in the Core?

EDIT: I am using WPF for my UI.

Comment: What's your UI technology (i.e. WPF, WinForms, or other)?  The answer for how to architect this will depend on the technology.

Comment: @Craig WPF. I edited my post to include this info for others too.

Comment: [MVVM Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) -- [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) -- [Introduction to the MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction)

Comment: You may need a little bit of code-behind to associate the `DataContext` with the View, but otherwise, you should be handling everything using binding against properties of your ViewModel.  Your ViewModel will expose a property of type `ICommand` like `RunCommand`, then in your View, the xaml for the button will bind the click to the "RunCommand" property.  WPF will do the magic of linking everything up, and it will just work.  As long as you ensure that the ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notifies for changes, the interface will be responsive to changes.

Comment: @Jimi , thanks, I read that article, but that is WAY over my head. Complicated as hell. Is there no simpler approach?

Comment: *WPF was designed to make it easy to build applications using the MVVM pattern[...]* -- *[...]The single most important aspect of WPF that makes MVVM a great pattern to use is the data binding infrastructure. By binding properties of a view to a ViewModel, you get loose coupling between the two and entirely remove the need for writing code in a ViewModel that directly updates a view[...]* -- *Two other features of WPF that make this pattern so usable are data templates and the resource system. Data templates apply Views to ViewModel objects shown in the user interface[...]*. No there isn't.

Comment: @Jimi Well, I see. I guess I'll be back to spaghetti code. MVVM seems simple in theory, but even for such a simple example as in that article, the code gets incredibly complex. Not to mention having to pollute model code with event raise calls...

Comment: That's how most UI platforms work, not just WPF. Many examples you can find here or elsewhere make the assumption that you use DataBindings, Templates etc. If you don't, you'll get a suggestion that you should. Because you really should.  -- *pollute model code with event raise calls* that's not *pollution* at all, that's how you automate all UI updates, just setting a property value and more. You cannot do without this form of automation, no matter what pattern you adopt. Even if you write *spaghetti code*.

Comment: That's what your current attempt is missing: the knowledge of already existing patterns, as the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` or other forms of even-driven patterns.

Comment: @Jimi well, that's quite a steep learning curve after something as simple as interfaces. I will try to find some simpler examples, because as far as I can find right now, MVVM approach turns even the simplest "Hello world" application into a giant confusion of bindings, events, assignments of devil knows what, and makes code extremely unreadable. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places still. Anyway, thank you for trying to help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Re "pollute the model code with event raise calls," you're going to have to let the UI know that the data it displays has changed.  How else do you propose to do it?  `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't force you to do it everywhere, you do have the option of aggregating into a single big "refresh", with the understanding that your big "refresh" will need to know the name of everything that may need to be refreshed (increasing coupling).  Note that `<CallerMemberName>` makes it easy to write a single "Raise" routine that you can call with no arguments.

Comment: @Craig, well, the way I usually did it before, was to call appropriate UI command from the model to update the UI with correct data. Like in my example in the first post: `UI.DisplayResults(calculationResult)`. Is there a tutorial for this MVVM thing for absolute beginners, without assuming knowledge of anything? Everything I'm finding so far makes me feel like a moron, though I've written dozens of pretty complex applications.

Comment: Jimi's middle link is daunting, the app is really more complicated than I would ideally want to see for a pedagogic example, but there is one bit in the middle that's potentially helpful which is Figure 10 which gives a way of linking View to ViewModel so that you don't have to set up the data context manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified WPF example based on the code you provided.

```xaml
<!-- Details elided, but if you add a new window in a WPF project,
you'll start out with what you need -->
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Run Calculations" Command="{Binding RunCalculationsCommand}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Results}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```vb
Public Class Model
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    'In C#, this can be made into an extension, but I don't think 
    'the VB event model gives us granular enough access to do this.
    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    'Boilerplate nature of visible properties can be annoying; I don't
    'have any suggested workarounds beyond generated code.
    Private _Results As String
    Public Property Results As String
        Get
            Return _Results
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Results = value
            RaisePropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    'ActionCommand implementation left as an exercise for the reader.
    Public ReadOnly Property RunCalculationsCommand As ICommand = 
        New ActionCommand(AddressOf RunCalculations)

    Public Sub RunCalculations()
        Dim calculationResult As String = (5 + 5).ToString()
        Results = calculationResult
    End Sub
End Class
```

The last thing that this needs is code to set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to an instance of `Model`.  For this example, it would probably be most straightforward to assign a new instance in the constructor (trying to put a parameter on the main window ctor I think would cause issues with the framework).

Comment: Thank you, @Craig. This is far more understandable than anything I've found so far. As I understand, this is not MVVM, because there is no ViewModel - View ties directly to the model (I assume that is what RunCalculations command is for, because WPF cannot bind to a regular Sub, only ICommand, right?). Are there any issues to this approach compared to MVVM? This seems far more readable and less confusing to me.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas You're right, I did omit the viewmodel in this case.  The main issue with this approach is that you'll have display-oriented logic in the model, which may pose issues for unit testing (and general cleanliness of the business logic).  You're right that WPF can only bind to a command---note that the command has some additional capability, as there is a `CanExecute` which takes care of enabling/disabling the button.

Comment: If you should add a viewmodel in between, it can be a bit tedious as it will have a bunch of passthrough properties that only exist to link to the model.  And the model will still need to issue notifications for changes, though at least the viewmodel can do a centralized catch-and-rethrow of the event (keeping in mind that WPF is only interested in notifications that issue from the DataContext, so the event would need to re-issue with the viewmodel as the sender).